# Add conditional elements to a state object in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a state array myVar.

I only want to add a certain elements to the array based on a condition, like this

if condition

```
myVar = [1, 2, 3]
```

else

```
myVar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So the first elements are there in both cases, the last two only if a condition is not met, all this when declaring the variable in the constructor as part of the state.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [Array.proptype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method with callback function. `e.g. [1].concat(true ? 2 : [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using `Array.concat()`

```
const myVar = [1, 2, 3].concat(true ? [4, 5] : []);
```